# how can I run ansible molecule without colors?

Tags: ansible, molecule

When running molecule the logs display with colors:

```
 molecule lint -s preprod
 --> [36mValidating schema /home/singuliere/software/enough/infrastructure/molecule/letsencrypt-nginx/molecule.yml.[0m
```

[0m[0m[0m[32mValidation completed successfully.[0m
[0m[0m[0m--> [36mValidating schema /home/singuliere/software/enough/infrastructure/molecule/postfix/molecule.yml.[0m
     ...

which can be disabled by piping the output to `cat` (it only shows when the output is a tty)

```
 molecule lint -s preprod | cat
```

--> Validating schema /home/singuliere/software/enough/infrastructure/molecule/letsencrypt-nginx/molecule.yml.
Validation completed successfully.
     ...

Is there a permanent way to do the same? I tried setting [ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-nocolor)=true in the environment but it does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this behaviour is hardcoded.

You can patch molecule's logger class to disable colours.
Find module's path with `python -c 'import molecule; print(molecule.__file__)'`.
Modify `logger.py` in that folder:

```
def color_text(color, msg):
    return msg
    # return '{}{}{}'.format(color, msg, colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `molecule --version` → `6.0.2` this works:

```
export PY_COLORS=0 
molecule --version
# no colors in output
```